# IDE Android Studio ToolBar (TOP) missing?

Tags: android-studio

I installed the last version of Android Studio v3.1.4

but after creating a project i found the IDE not showing toolbar in TOP

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

[image: Android Studio screenshot2]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are talking about an Android Studio problem in Windows OS. I will have answer for both Windows & Linux.

Be sure to close Android Studio before doing this.

**Easy way**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
Search **Appearance** (Make sure the search tab is highlighted with *All*)
Now click *Appearance*
Check the **Main Menu** Option
Done

**Hard Way**
(Its good to have two solutions for one problem)

If the above solution does not work for you, then you can try to solve this the hard way which also fixes other problems that causes Android Studio to crash.

**On Windows**

Go to folder `C/Users/{USERNAME}/`
then there will be a folder called **AndroidStudio** maybe with the version *number*.
E.g. - AndroidStudio4.0
*If you can not see the above folder be sure to* ***Enable Hidden files and Folders in the View tab*** in file explorer

Open that folder and delete the folder with the name **config**.
That's it. Now launch Android Studio and the problem will have been fixed.

**On Linux** (Except Kali Linux because it always runs as root)

```
cd /home/{USERNAME}/
```

browseToUserFolder:
[image: browseToUserFolder]

Now run command

```
ls -al
```

Find the AndroidStudio folder:
[image: finding androistudio folder]

Now you may have a Folder having name **.AndroidStudio4.0** or **.AndroidStudio3.3**.............. Something like that depending on the version of the Android Studio is installed

Now go to that folder and delete the folder with the name name **config**

```
cd .AndroidSudio4.0
rm -rf config
```

delete the config folder:
[image: delete the config folder]

Now start Android Studio, everything will be back to the default.

Answer (score 7):

For Android Studio 4.0.1, you can go to View > Appearance and toggle Toolbar:

[image: Toggle main toolbar]

The checkmark to the left of Toolbar means that Android Studio's Main Toolbar is toggled on and currently displays. No checkmark indicates the Main Toolbar is toggled off and disabled.

Answer (score 2):

go to search, type appearance and enable view appearance in main menu.

Answer (score 1):

You could press `Alt + v` to open `view` menu, and toggle `toolbar` like below fig:

[image]

Comment: I see, but press alt+v not take effect? I think shortcut is should valid

Comment: cannot test that... while this is a keyboard shortcut for a menu which is not there. uninstalling & reinstalling might be rather an option. have searched, but could find nothing.

Comment: strangely indeed! why no menu? maybe a bug or issue. Try reinstall.

Comment: i reinstalled it with new copy downloaded but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Android Studio 3.0+, you can access any action/menu:

1. Press `Shift` twice, It will launch **Search Everywhere** option
2. Now, Select the `Action` tab and type **Menu**
3. You will see an option **View | Appearance: Main Menu**, switch it on

   You're done.

[image: Search Everywhere option menu]